# Stolen car in GTA 5 online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought an expensive car in GTA 5 Online for Shark Card. This car was stolen and there was no tracker or insurance on it.

How can I get this car back?

Comment: How did you buy the car in the game?  Via one of the websites in the game? Or was it one of the vehicles that are dropped off at a location in the world for you to reach and acquire the vehicle?

Comment: It was bought threw in game website. ( Car store in Web mobile phone)

Comment: Was it delivered to your garage?  If so, it should be on your insurance list when you call Mors Mutual.  When you buy cars off the websites, they are delivered to your garage and automatically come with insurance.  However, some of the vehicles like monster trucks don't get delivered to your garage, in which case those vehicles are lost once destroyed and will need to be repurchased.  Basically, anything too big to fit in a garage, or anything too powerful like the Rhino Tank will fall into this category.  What was the specific vehicle anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All cars purchased from the Web Stores come with insurance as standard. Open your phone, go to contacts, and call 'Mors Mutual'. You should be presented with a list of cars, and the car you are missing should be on there.